# Unity 5 two-sided cloth plane

Tags: shader, game-physics, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make some curtains for a game with the cloth component in Unity 5, with the new Standard shader. If I make them with a plane I can only see one side of it (obviously), and if I try to make the curtains with a thin cube it looks really buggy and it doesn't behave like a plane would.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways you can approach this.

1, You can create a two sided plane in any of the 3D graphic programs (Maya, Blender... etc.) then import that into your scene.

2, You can use a two sided shader.

3, You can use two different plane objects parented together and work on the parent object later. [I don't really recommend this but it can certainly work as well...]

Some of the particle shaders are rendering both sides like the "Particles/Alpha Blended" but if that's not good for you then you can also make two-sided versions of other shaders by duplicating your selected shader into your assets and setting it's [culling value](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html) to Off.

Note: Setting the culling to off may not work for lit shaders and you may have to invert the normals too however that's heavy on performance. It's better to use another method in that case.

Comment: I tried creating a two sided plane in blender and it didn't work after I imported it to Unity. I went with the second solution, even though I wanted to use a PBS. Thank you!